# Images on SSL enabled site with Internet explorer

Tags: ssl, cross-domain

I have a problem with my site after implementation of SSL that images do not appear. The scenario is that images come from images.domain.com (hosted on Amazon S3) and my certificate is for www.domain.com.

This problem only seems to happen in IE and not in any other browsers.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/196819/images-on-ssl-enabled-site-with-internet-explorer/196833#196833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to "mixed content" - HTTPS pages which have HTTP resources (images, scripts, etc) embedded.

The point of using HTTPS is to ensure that only the originating server and the client have access to the secured page. However, in theory it might be possible for this security to be compromised if HTTP resources are embedded - a server might intercept an unsecured javascript file and inject some code to alter the secured page onload.

Most browsers will indicate that a secure page has mixed content by altering the "secure lock" icon, either by showing the lock as open or broken, or by making the icon red (Chrome displayed a skull and crossbones for a short time, but they realised that this was a bit serious for the potential threat level).

Internet Explorer (depending on the version) will display a message either asking whether the insecure content should be shown (IE<=7), or whether only the secure content should be shown (IE>=8). It sounds like you have somehow disabled this message to always hide the insecure content, however that's not the default behaviour.

I think the best solution for you is to replace your S3 links with HTTPS versions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a web developer, but someone who often deals with the crap experience that is IE.  I am not sure what version you are using, but you do not have a wildcard SSL cert (i.e. *.domain.com), so does it have something to do with an old-school limitation in 3rd party images?

See [here for what I allude to above](https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/6293.htm) and a very good explanation of [how IE caches cross-domain HTTPS content, specifically images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/).  I am not sure what the solution is, but I was curious so I researched a little myself and this might help.